# Is there a method to get all groups in regular expression with wildcard in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Just like the follow code, there is not all groups. Is there a method to get all groups? Thanks~

```py
import re

res = re.match(r'(?: ([a-z]+) ([0-9]+))*', ' a 1 b 2 c 3')

# echo ('c', '3'), but I want ('a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3')
res.groups()
```

Comment: "re.findall" or "re.finditer" may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to iterate the matches, appending each result to an empty tuple:

```
import re

res = tuple()
matches = re.finditer(r' ([a-z]+) ([0-9]+)', ' a 1 b 2 c 3')
for m in matches:
    res = res + m.groups()
```

Output:

```
('a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3')
```

Note that in the regex the outer group is removed as it is not required with `finditer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating a capture group, which gives you the value of the last iteration which is `('c', '3')`

You can repeat the pattern to check if the whole string if of that format, and then split on a space and wrap it in a tuple.

```
import re

m = re.match(r"(?: [a-z]+ [0-9]+)*$", " a 1 b 2 c 3")
if m:
    print(tuple(m.group().split()))
```

Output

```
('a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3')
```